# Meteor: Exporting rendered template for offline use

Tags: meteor, meteor-collection2

I have an online tool for users to build and preview slideshow presentations (uploading images, editing text).

Would there be a way to "export" the content of a rendered slideshow for offline use? This would mean the user could view the presentation locally in a browser using only static files.

Comment: Hard to say without knowing more about how you do this, i.e., without any code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 
    `var myRenderedHTML = Blaze.toHTMLWithData(templateYouWantToCache, dataUsedToRenderTemplate);`

Then use something like the [Filesaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) library to force download of that content as an HTML file. (as in the last demo on [this page](http://eligrey.com/demos/FileSaver.js/))